# Como mostrar datos en pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código que me extrae los datos de una api del clima, tengo los datos en consola, necesito extraer los datos de:
`main: temp`, y el `name: barranquilla` y mostrarlos en el `content-text`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pieza clima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src="Videos/viento2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="content-text"></div>
        <div id="contenido">
<script>

    var _from = document.location.pathname.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    _from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html', '').replace('index_', ''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo


     $.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/"+_from,
    success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
    }});
  </script>



<script>
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
//se ejecutara despues de 2 segundos
setTimeout(mostrarTexto, 2000);
//se ejecutara despues de 9 segundos
setTimeout(OcultarTexto, 9000);
function mostrarTexto(){
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","overlay");
}
function OcultarTexto(){
div = document.getElementById('contenido');
div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
}//end function OcultarTexto
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

**Código en la consola:**

```
{base: "stations", clouds: {…}, cod: 200, coord: {…}, dt: 1550775600, …}
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 0}
cod: 200
coord: {lat: 10.96, lon: -74.8}
dt: 1550775600
id: 3689147
main:
humidity: 52
pressure: 1008
temp: 34.39
temp_max: 36
temp_min: 32
__proto__: Object
name: "Barranquilla"
sys: {country: "CO", id: 8584, message: 0.0038, sunrise: 1550747840, sunset: 1550790493, …}
visibility: 10000
weather: Array(1)
0: {description: "clear sky", icon: "01d", id: 800, main: "Clear"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
wind: {deg: 10, speed: 6.2}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Probaste con `result.name` y `result.temp`?

Comment: Eso era lo que buscaba, sabes como ponerlo en el content-text? @alanfcm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres asi:

```
$("#content-text").html(result.name + " " + result.temp);
```